# Specifying dependency between controllers if the required controller was initialized by {{render}} helper

Tags: ember.js

I wonder if there is a way to specify a required controller (without its re-initialization) using the `needs` parameter, if the controller was already initialized by the `{{render "'.' or '/' containing path"}}` helper.

For example:

```
//tasks.hbs
{{render "tasks/create_task"}}

//tasks_controller.js
App.TasksController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: 'tasksCreateTask',

  aMethod: function() {
    // The following code causes re-initialization of the 
    // App.TasksCreateTaskController, previously initialized by the render helper.
    this.get('controllers.tasksCreateTask');
  }
});
```

The reason of the re-initialization is apparently the different key for the same controller in the ember controllers cache: the key `controllers:tasks.create_tasks` exists, but not the `controllers:tasksCreateTasks`. I think it might be a bug.

Please, help me to get rid off the re-initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug.  The name of the controller is `App.TasksCreateTaskController`, which means to use it in `{{render}}` you need to do:

```
{{render "tasks.create_task"}}
```

The format you are using:

```
{{render "tasks/create_task"}}
```

means you want Ember.js to render the controller `Tasks.CreateTaskController` (notice the namespace `Tasks` instead of `App`).  The `/` is used to tell Ember.js to use a different namespace (which I assume is not what you want).

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to mention that I was using Ember RC1. I updated it to RC2 today and the problem disappeared.